# Working with strings.xml and translations

Tags: android, localization

I'm developing an app, right now the default language is italian and I have placed all my texts in the `strings.xml` file.

In this app there is a section about some people and I created my own database table and stored the text.

How can I just save the string id to get the translated content based on phone locale?

Right now at the boot I populate the DB and it save all the text, I'd like to save just the `R.string.something`.

Something like:

```
String resource = mydb.get("description"); // This shoul be the R.string
textview.setText(resource); // Teanslated content
```

Is this possibile?
Is there a standard for this?

Comment: You should provide all the translations in several strings.xml resource files. Then probably save the language in your apps SharedPreferences. Something like "it" or "en" or ... And switch your app's locale accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just store your resource id as integer in database and can fetch integer type from database and can set that int to textview like

```
    textView.setText(integerResourceIdFromDatabase);
```

I have created my database class as follows:

```
package com.demo.sqlitedemo.databasehelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


private static String DATABASE_NAME = "Demo_db";
private static int VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_STRING_IDS = "string_ids";
private static final String STRING_ID = "string_id";

private static final String STRING_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_STRING_IDS + "( " + STRING_ID
        + " integer primary key );";


public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(STRING_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STRING_IDS);
    onCreate(db);
}


public void insertId(int stringId) {

    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(STRING_ID, stringId);

    database.insert(TABLE_STRING_IDS, "", values);

    database.close();

}

public int getStringId() {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_STRING_IDS, new String[]{STRING_ID}
            , null, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(STRING_ID));

    database.close();
    return id;
}

}
```

and used it in main activity like this

```
dbHelper.insertId(R.string.my_string);
```

To fetch data

```
textView.setText(dbHelper.getStringId());
```

this works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I have a db insert that get `R.string.person_bio` stored as Integer as you said but with setText I get an actual integer instead of text

Comment: @ChristianGiupponi I think you might have casted your int to String somewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

Ypu have to create multi language resource directory under in /res. use qualifiers on your strings i believe fr is for france. So if you have a resource folder called values-fr, then anyone with french on their phone will get the french string file located in that folder and everyone else will get the string file in the values folder.

Resource structure looks like this

```
Project/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-es/
           strings.xml
       values-fr/
           strings.xml
```

Here is string for france language :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">ask le monde !</string>
</resources>
```

Now whenever you change the device language, project will take string according to device language.

Comment: Thanks but I have something like: `person.getBio()` and I need to get the correct language for that text. I do not have hardcoded string because I have multiple person in my DB.

Answer (score 0):

you don’t need to store that on database 
if you store all your string on string.xml and showed the text from there,then create xml for every language on values folder and name like that

> values-pt ,
>   values-es ,
>   values-br ,
>   and what ever you want .
>   now just put the respected string in each file.And then when user change their language app will also take the values from respected language file if it exists.

Answer (score -1):

please refer below link

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

you can create translated-text several strings.xml resource files based on locale.

> Suppose that your application's default language is English. Suppose also that you want to localize all the text in your application to French, and most of the text in your application (everything except the application's title) to Japanese. In this case, you could create three alternative strings.xml files, each stored in a locale-specific resource directory:
>
> - res/values/strings.xml
>     Contains English text for all the strings that the application uses, including text for a string named title.
> - res/values-fr/strings.xml
>     Contain French text for all the strings, including title.
> - res/values-ja/strings.xml
>     Contain Japanese text for all the strings except title.

If your Java-based code refers to R.string.title, here is what happens at runtime:

- If the device is set to any language other than French, Android loads title from the res/values/strings.xml file.
- If the device is set to French, Android loads title from the res/values-fr/strings.xml file.
- Notice that if the device is set to Japanese, Android looks for title in the res/values-ja/strings.xml file. But because no such string is included in that file, Android falls back to the default, and loads title in English from the res/values/strings.xml file.